# How to set ADR Base directory correctly on OracleDB on Linux?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux

Installed Oracle Database on Linux based OS. Listener is ok. But Oracle is not. (I changed all angular brackets to vertical, because parser not shows angular brackets)

> ORA-48108: invalid value given for the diagnostic_dest init.ora parameter
>   ORA-48140: the specified ADR Base directory does not exist
>   [/volumeX/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/|ORACLE_BASE|]
>   ORA-48187: specified directory does not exist

Thats line in initXE.ora and init.ora:

> diagnostic_dest='|ORACLE_BASE|'

Result of echo $ORACLE_BASE:

> /u01/app/oracle

u01 is a symlink of volumeX directory.

How to solve this problem?

It is on Linux DiskStation 3.2.40.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set:

```
diagnostic_dest=/u01/app/oracle
```

or

```
diagnostic_dest=/volumeX/app/oracle
```

The error message you receive indicates that the value for this parameter is currently stored in a format that the database can not interpret. When this happens, the database will search for this directory in $ORACLE_HOME/dbs as seen below the ORA-48140 line.

Or you can just simply delete this line, and the parameter value will default to `$ORACLE_BASE`.