# ORA-48108 / ORA-48140 / ORA-48187 - diagnostic_dest value error(s) - init files / control files

Tags: linux, oracle-12c, installation, sqlplus, parameter

**This is all testing / training - none of this is related to a production env**

*Using ORACLE DB 12c + UNIX/LINUX 64-bit on an VM.*

.

Hi Guys! 
I am running in the below error(s) and seem unable to solve it.
Can you please help?

```
SQL> STARTUP NOMOUNT; 
ORA-48108: invalid value given for the diagnostic_dest init.ora parameter 
ORA-48140: the specified ADR Base directory does not exist [/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs/<ORACLE_BASE>] 
ORA-48187: specified directory does not exist Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory Additional information: 1
```

DB Details:

```
[oracle@ol12c dbs]$ echo $ORACLE_BASE
/u01/app/oracle

echo $ORACLE_HOME
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1

[oracle@ol12c dbs]$ ls -a
.   hc_cdb1.dat   init.ora       lkCDB1     spfilecdb1.ora   STARTUP
..  hc_pridb.dat  initpridb.ora  orapwcdb1  spfilepridb.ora
[oracle@ol12c dbs]$ pwd
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs

[oracle@ol12c dbs]$ echo $DB_NAME
pridb

[oracle@ol12c dbs]$ env | grep ORA
ORACLE_UNQNAME=cdb1
ORACLE_SID=pridb
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
ORACLE_HOSTNAME=ol12c.localdomain
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1
```

init.ora contains: 
`diagnostic_dest='<ORACLE_BASE>'`

initpridb.ora contains: 
`diagnostic_dest='u01/app/oracle'`

** 
I have already changed the value to `'<ORACLE_BASE>'` / `'/u01/app/oracle'` / `'/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1'` / `'|ORACLE_BASE|'`, no luck - all the same error.

As per my previous research:

- [ORA-48108 & ORA-01034](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161954/ora-48108-ora-01034/161958)
- [How to set ADR Base directory correctly on OracleDB on Linux?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87225/how-to-set-adr-base-directory-correctly-on-oracledb-on-linux)

When I try to start up like the below:

```
SQL> startup nomount pfile=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs/initpridb.ora;
```

I receive the same errors, see below:

```
ORA-01261: Parameter db_recovery_file_dest destination string cannot be translated
ORA-01262: Stat failed on a file destination directory
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

I've noticed that whatever I change the diagnostic_dest value to, it searches using that value + ORACLE_BASE. 
If I flip them (`'<ORACLE_BASE>/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs'`) it will end up searching in `'<ORACLE_BASE>/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs/<ORACLE_BASE>'`

I am **very** new to database and am creating an new db on the same host.
After this db has been created I will create another one to use as a Physical Standby DB using Oracle Data Guard. 
Please when suggesting an action, act like you talk to someone that has no clue! :) :)

**Thank you in advance!**

.

---

.

**UPDATE**

See details of files:

```
[oracle@ol12c dbs]$ cat initpridb.ora
# 
# $Header: rdbms/admin/init.ora /main/24 2012/02/03 08:24:01 ysarig Exp $ 
# 
# Copyright (c) 1991, 1997, 1998 by Oracle Corporation
# NAME
#   init.ora
# FUNCTION
# NOTES
# MODIFIED
#     ysarig     02/01/12  - Renaming flash_recovery_area to
#                            fast_recovery_area
#     ysarig     05/14/09  - Updating compatible to 11.2
#     ysarig     08/13/07  - Fixing the sample for 11g
#     atsukerm   08/06/98 -  fix for 8.1.
#     hpiao      06/05/97 -  fix for 803
#     glavash    05/12/97 -  add oracle_trace_enable comment
#     hpiao      04/22/97 -  remove ifile=, events=, etc.
#     alingelb   09/19/94 -  remove vms-specific stuff
#     dpawson    07/07/93 -  add more comments regarded archive start
#     maporter   10/29/92 -  Add vms_sga_use_gblpagfile=TRUE 
#     jloaiza    03/07/92 -  change ALPHA to BETA 
#     danderso   02/26/92 -  change db_block_cache_protect to _db_block_cache_p
#     ghallmar   02/03/92 -  db_directory -> db_domain 
#     maporter   01/12/92 -  merge changes from branch 1.8.308.1 
#     maporter   12/21/91 -  bug 76493: Add control_files parameter 
#     wbridge    12/03/91 -  use of %c in archive format is discouraged 
#     ghallmar   12/02/91 -  add global_names=true, db_directory=us.acme.com 
#     thayes     11/27/91 -  Change default for cache_clone 
#     jloaiza    08/13/91 -         merge changes from branch 1.7.100.1 
#     jloaiza    07/31/91 -         add debug stuff 
#     rlim       04/29/91 -         removal of char_is_varchar2 
#   Bridge     03/12/91 - log_allocation no longer exists
#   Wijaya     02/05/91 - remove obsolete parameters
#
##############################################################################
# Example INIT.ORA file
#
# This file is provided by Oracle Corporation as a starting point for
# customizing the Oracle Database installation for your site.    
#
# NOTE: The values that are used in this file are example values only.
# You may want to adjust those values for your specific requirements. 
# You might also consider using the Database Configuration Assistant     
# tool (DBCA) to create a server-side initialization parameter file
# and to size your initial set of tablespaces. See the
# Oracle Database 2 Day DBA guide for more information.
###############################################################################

# Change '<ORACLE_BASE>' to point to the oracle base (the one you specify at
# install time)

db_name='ORCL'
memory_target=1G
processes = 150
audit_file_dest='<ORACLE_BASE>/admin/orcl/adump'
audit_trail ='db'
db_block_size=8192
db_domain=''
db_recovery_file_dest='<ORACLE_BASE>/fast_recovery_area'
db_recovery_file_dest_size=2G
diagnostic_dest='/u01/app/oracle'
dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=ORCLXDB)'
open_cursors=300 
remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'
undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'
# You may want to ensure that control files are created on separate physical
# devices
control_files = (ora_control1, ora_control2)
compatible ='11.2.0'
```

And

```
[oracle@ol12c dbs]$ cat init.ora
# 
# $Header: rdbms/admin/init.ora /main/24 2012/02/03 08:24:01 ysarig Exp $ 
# 
# Copyright (c) 1991, 1997, 1998 by Oracle Corporation
# NAME
#   init.ora
# FUNCTION
# NOTES
# MODIFIED
#     ysarig     02/01/12  - Renaming flash_recovery_area to
#                            fast_recovery_area
#     ysarig     05/14/09  - Updating compatible to 11.2
#     ysarig     08/13/07  - Fixing the sample for 11g
#     atsukerm   08/06/98 -  fix for 8.1.
#     hpiao      06/05/97 -  fix for 803
#     glavash    05/12/97 -  add oracle_trace_enable comment
#     hpiao      04/22/97 -  remove ifile=, events=, etc.
#     alingelb   09/19/94 -  remove vms-specific stuff
#     dpawson    07/07/93 -  add more comments regarded archive start
#     maporter   10/29/92 -  Add vms_sga_use_gblpagfile=TRUE 
#     jloaiza    03/07/92 -  change ALPHA to BETA 
#     danderso   02/26/92 -  change db_block_cache_protect to _db_block_cache_p
#     ghallmar   02/03/92 -  db_directory -> db_domain 
#     maporter   01/12/92 -  merge changes from branch 1.8.308.1 
#     maporter   12/21/91 -  bug 76493: Add control_files parameter 
#     wbridge    12/03/91 -  use of %c in archive format is discouraged 
#     ghallmar   12/02/91 -  add global_names=true, db_directory=us.acme.com 
#     thayes     11/27/91 -  Change default for cache_clone 
#     jloaiza    08/13/91 -         merge changes from branch 1.7.100.1 
#     jloaiza    07/31/91 -         add debug stuff 
#     rlim       04/29/91 -         removal of char_is_varchar2 
#   Bridge     03/12/91 - log_allocation no longer exists
#   Wijaya     02/05/91 - remove obsolete parameters
#
##############################################################################
# Example INIT.ORA file
#
# This file is provided by Oracle Corporation as a starting point for
# customizing the Oracle Database installation for your site.    
#
# NOTE: The values that are used in this file are example values only.
# You may want to adjust those values for your specific requirements. 
# You might also consider using the Database Configuration Assistant     
# tool (DBCA) to create a server-side initialization parameter file
# and to size your initial set of tablespaces. See the
# Oracle Database 2 Day DBA guide for more information.
###############################################################################

# Change '<ORACLE_BASE>' to point to the oracle base (the one you specify at
# install time)

db_name='ORCL'
memory_target=1G
processes = 150
audit_file_dest='<ORACLE_BASE>/admin/orcl/adump'
audit_trail ='db'
db_block_size=8192
db_domain=''
db_recovery_file_dest='<ORACLE_BASE>/fast_recovery_area'
db_recovery_file_dest_size=2G
diagnostic_dest='<ORACLE_BASE>'
dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=ORCLXDB)'
open_cursors=300 
remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'
undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'
# You may want to ensure that control files are created on separate physical
# devices
control_files = (ora_control1, ora_control2)
compatible ='11.2.0'
```

and

```
[oracle@ol12c dbs]$ echo $ORACLE_SID
pridb

[oracle@ol12c dbs]$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1

[oracle@ol12c dbs]$ echo $ORACLE_BASE
/u01/app/oracle

[oracle@ol12c dbs]$ echo $DB_NAME
pridb
```

.

---

.

**UPDATE 2**

I updated the init files as suggested. 
Changed `<ORACLE_BASE>` to the actual path: `/u01/app/oracle/`

```
[oracle@ol12c dbs]$ cat initpridb.ora
...
...
db_name='ORCL'
memory_target=1G
processes = 150
audit_file_dest='/u01/app/oracle/admin/orcl/adump'
audit_trail ='db'
db_block_size=8192
db_domain=''
db_recovery_file_dest='/u01/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area'
db_recovery_file_dest_size=2G
diagnostic_dest='/u01/app/oracle'
dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=ORCLXDB)'
open_cursors=300 
remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'
undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'
```

and

```
[oracle@ol12c dbs]$ cat init.ora
...
...
db_name='ORCL'
memory_target=1G
processes = 150
audit_file_dest='/u01/app/oracle/admin/orcl/adump'
audit_trail ='db'
db_block_size=8192
db_domain=''
db_recovery_file_dest='/u01/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area'
db_recovery_file_dest_size=2G
diagnostic_dest='/u01/app/oracle'
dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=ORCLXDB)'
open_cursors=300 
remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'
undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'
```

I get the error when not selecting the pfile manually:

```
SQL> STARTUP NOMOUNT;
ORA-48108: invalid value given for the diagnostic_dest init.ora parameter
ORA-48140: the specified ADR Base directory does not exist [/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs/<ORACLE_BASE>]
ORA-48187: specified directory does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 1
```

But it works! :) (I just ran into a new issue but that is probably unrelated to this)

```
SQL> startup nomount pfile=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs/initpridb.ora;
ORA-09925: Unable to create audit trail file
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 9925
```

I also noticed that the db_name is set to ORCL for both. Not sure if this will create further issues.

.

---

.

**UPDATE 3**

FOR: `ORA-09925: Unable to create audit trail file`

I checked the Oracle Knowledge Base Documentation:
ORA-09925: Unable To Create Audit Trail File at Startup ([Doc ID 2267223.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2267223.1))
I am following the steps towards solution.
Output of point b:

```
[oracle@ol12c ~]$ ps -ef|grep LOCAL
oracle    8211  8172  0 14:06 ?        00:00:00 oraclepridb (DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))
oracle    8448  8408  0 14:18 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto LOCAL
```

And I tried:

```
[oracle@ol12c ~]$ strace -frT -o /tmp/strace.1.log -p 8211
Process 8211 attached
```

But this seems to be stuck/loading and thus - I am stuck again.

.

---

.

**UPDATE 4**

All got solved. ORACLE instance started.

The last error (ORA-09925) has been resolved by updating the original value of the `audit_file_dest` parameter from to the correct path.
From `audit_file_dest='/u01/app/oracle/admin/orcl/adump'` To >> `audit_file_dest='/u01/app/oracle/admin/pridb/adump'`

```
SQL> startup nomount pfile=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs/initpridb.ora;
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1073741824 bytes
Fixed Size          2932632 bytes
Variable Size         671088744 bytes
Database Buffers      394264576 bytes
Redo Buffers            5455872 bytes
```

.

**Thank you all for your help!**

Comment: Prove that the oracle OS user can write to that directory.  `touch` is a quick method.  Is the drive (for that directory) mounted in a Read Only state?

Comment: edit your question with your complete `initpridb.ora`. I assume you're reading some sort of install guide - you should not be using `<ORACLE_BASE>` etc - the guide you are following will assume that you have substituted `<ORACLE_BASE>` in all places in the config files for the proper location, ie: `/u01/app/oracle`. The 2nd question you have linked actually explains how to fix this

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ Thank you for your comment! I've updated the original post with further details. I hope I am providing you the correct information. Indeed I am working with user-guids, Oracle Knowledge Base documentation and other online resources. :)

Comment: From the files themselves: `# Change '<ORACLE_BASE>' to point to the oracle base (the one you specify at
# install time)` -- Do that? Replace the exact string `<ORACLE_BASE>` with the string `/u01/app/oracle`, so for example you will have:
`db_recovery_file_dest='/u01/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area'`
etc

Comment: @MichaelKutz
Thank you for helping me!
I must admit that I am not familiar (yet) with the touch command.
I went through this: http://www.linfo.org/touch.html
If I am not mistaken this command can be used to access/modification times and create new (empty) files.

I also found: https://serverfault.com/questions/193971/determine-if-filesystem-or-partition-is-mounted-ro-or-rw-via-bash-script
Which states that:
"This little one-liner will pop-out something if a ro file system exists.
grep "[[:space:]]ro[[:space:],]" /proc/mounts "

Comment: @MichaelKutz 

`[oracle@ol12c dbs]$ grep "[[:space:]]ro[[:space:],]" /proc/mounts 
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0`

I hope this answers your question. :)

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ - On it!

Comment: I dont know how you installed your Oracle software, but let us assume it is intalled correctly. How did you create the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore `init.ora`, that isn't used.  You want `init<SID>.ora`. In your case, this seems to be `initpridb.ora`

This comment in this file that you have got your hands on seems to have been ignored:

> Change '<ORACLE_BASE>' to point to the oracle base (the one you specify at install time)

You still have:

```
audit_file_dest='<ORACLE_BASE>/admin/orcl/adump'
```

Modify this to:

```
/u01/app/oracle/admin/orcl/adump
```

And try again.

Comment: YEY ! :) 
 
`SQL> startup nomount pfile=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1/dbs/initpridb.ora;
ORA-09925: Unable to create audit trail file
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 9925`

Much love towards you! Thank you for your help!
Moving on to fixing this new issue but I think it is unrelated to this one.

Comment: I checked the Oracle Knowledge Base Documentation:
ORA-09925: Unable To Create Audit Trail File at Startup (Doc ID 2267223.1)
I am following the steps towards solution.
Output of point b:

`[oracle@ol12c ~]$ ps -ef|grep LOCAL
oracle    8211  8172  0 14:06 ?        00:00:00 oraclepridb (DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))
oracle    8448  8408  0 14:18 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto LOCAL`

And I tried:
`[oracle@ol12c ~]$ strace -frT -o /tmp/strace.1.log -p 8211
Process 8211 attached`

But this seems to be stuck/loading and thus - I am stuck again. 
Can you help?